# How to get phone contact e-mail,phone and name using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

Hey there,

```
     String[] fromColumns = {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
        };

        String[] SELECTED_COLUMNS = {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
        };

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, fromColumns, null, null, null);


     SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, // context
                R.layout.list_view, // layout that defines the views for this list item.
                cursor, // The database cursor
                SELECTED_COLUMNS, // "from" - column names of the data to bind to the UI
                toViews, // TextViews that should display column in the "from" param
                0 // Flags used to determine the behavior of the adapter
        );
```

I have this code for getting phone contacts from phone and displaying on listView. However, I want to get e-mails of users aswell but i cannot do it with that way because its under CommonDataKinds.Email  so i need to create two cursor for that. I am confused about which cursor should I append to cursorAdapter to fetch both email and phone and name?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46572169/android-retrieve-name-phone-number-email-birthday-from-contact

Comment: query paramater Data.CONTENT_URI creates duplicate fields on listview when attached to cursor adapter. I think this is not exactly what I want